# Setting Datasource with encrypted password

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, jdbc, datasource

I have the following datasource configurations in my application which works

application.yaml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    batch:
      jdbcUrl: jdbc:mysql://localhost:33060/test
      username: root
      password: somepassowrd
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      minimumIdle: 5
      maximumPoolSize: 15
      idleTimeout: 30000
      connectionTimeout: 30000
    reader:
      jdbcUrl: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BL
      username: root
      password: someotherpassowrd
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      minimumIdle: 5
      maximumPoolSize: 15
      idleTimeout: 30000
      connectionTimeout: 30000
```

DatasourceConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
class DatasourceConfiguration() {
  @Bean(name = ["batchDatasource"])
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.batch")
  @BatchDataSource
  fun batchDataSource(): DataSource = HikariDataSource()

  @Bean(name = ["daoDatasource"])
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.reader")
  @Primary
  fun readerDataSource(): DataSource = HikariDataSource()
}
```

As said this works perfectly, but I now have a limitation that the passowrd in application.yaml is encrypted (hard limitation - can't change it).

How can I decrypt the password before creating the datasources?

I tried:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    batch:
      jdbcUrl: jdbc:mysql://localhost:33060/test
      username: root
      password: somepassowrd
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      minimumIdle: 5
      maximumPoolSize: 15
      idleTimeout: 30000
      connectionTimeout: 30000
    reader:
      jdbcUrl: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BL
      username: root
      password: someotherpassowrd
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      minimumIdle: 5
      maximumPoolSize: 15
      idleTimeout: 30000
      connectionTimeout: 30000
```

DatasourceConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
class DatasourceConfiguration() {
  @Bean(name = ["batchDatasource"])
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.batch")
  @BatchDataSource
  fun batchDataSource(@Value("${spring.datasource.batch.password}") encryptedPassword: String): DataSource = HikariDataSource()
    .apply(password = decryptPassword(encryptedPassword))

  @Bean(name = ["daoDatasource"])
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.reader")
  @Primary
  fun readerDataSource(@Value("${spring.datasource.reader.password}") encryptedPassword: String): DataSource = HikariDataSource()
    .apply(password = decryptPassword(encryptedPassword))
}
```

But it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it with a small workaround:
application.yaml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    batch:
      jdbcUrl: jdbc:mysql://localhost:33060/test
      username: root
      // setting encrypted-password instead of password
      encrypted-password: somepassowrd
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      minimumIdle: 5
      maximumPoolSize: 15
      idleTimeout: 30000
      connectionTimeout: 30000
    reader:
      jdbcUrl: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/BL
      username: root
      // setting encrypted-password instead of password
      encrypted-password: someotherpassowrd
      driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
      minimumIdle: 5
      maximumPoolSize: 15
      idleTimeout: 30000
      connectionTimeout: 30000
```

DatasourceConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
class DatasourceConfiguration() {
  @Bean(name = ["batchDatasource"])
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.batch")
  @BatchDataSource
  fun batchDataSource(@Value("${spring.datasource.batch.encrypted-password}") encryptedPassword: String): DataSource = HikariDataSource()
    .apply(password = decryptPassword(encryptedPassword))

  @Bean(name = ["daoDatasource"])
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.reader")
  @Primary
  fun readerDataSource(@Value("${spring.datasource.reader.encrypted-password}") encryptedPassword: String): DataSource = HikariDataSource()
    .apply(password = decryptPassword(encryptedPassword))
}
```

Explanation:
What I figured is that whatever I set in the `apply` is clause being overridden by the `@ConfigurationProperties`.

So instead of declaring a `password` property in the `application.yaml`, I set a different property - `encrypted-password`, so `@ConfigurationProperties` won't override the password.

This way I can take the `encrypted-password`, decrypt it and set it as password in the `apply` clause